# Java Generics, support "Specialization"? Conceptual similarities to C++ Templates?

Tags: java, c++, generics, template-specialization

I know quite a bit how to use **C++-Templates** -- not an expert, mind you. With **Java Generics** (and Scala, for that matter), I have my diffuculties. Maybe, because I try to translate my C++ knowledge to the Java world. I read elsewhere, "they are nothing alike: Java Generics are only syntactic sugar saving casts, C++ Templates are only a glorified Preprocessor" :-)

I am quite sure, both is a bit simplified a view. So, to understand the big and the subtle differences, I try to start with **Specialization**:

In **C++** I can design a **Template** (class of function) that acts on *any* type `T` that supports my required operations:

```
template<typename T>
T plus(T a, T b) { return a.add(b); }
```

This now potentially adds the `plus()` operation to any type that can `add()`.[note1][1]

Thus, if `T` supports the `add(T)` my template woll work. If it doesn't, 
The compiler will not complain as long as I do not use `plus()`. In Python 
we call this *"duck typing"*: *If it acts like a duck, quacks like a duck,
it *is* a duck.* (Of course, with using type_traits this is modified a bit,
but as long as we have no concepts, this is how C++ Templates work, right?)

I guess, thats how **Generics in Java** work as well, isn't it? The generic type I device is used as a "template" how to operate on any anything I try to put in there, right? As far as I understand I can (or must?) put some **constraints** on the type arguments: If I want to use `add` in my template, I have to declare the type argument to `implement Addable`. Correct? So, no "duck typing" (for better or worse).

Now, in **C++** I can choose to **specialize** on a type that has no `add()`:

```
template<>
T plus<MyX>(MyX a, MyX b) { return a + b; }
```

And even if *all other* types still can use the "default" implementation, now I added a special one for `MyX` -- with no runtime overhead.

Is there any **Java Generics** mechanism that has the same purpose? Of course, in programming everything is doable, but I mean *conceptually*, without any tricks and magic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, generics in Java don't work this way.

With generics you can't do anything which would not be possible without Generics - you just avoid to have to write lots of casts, and the compiler ensures that everything is typesafe (as long as you don't get some warnings or suppress those).

So, for each type variable you can only call the methods defined in its bounds (no duck typing).

Also, there is no code generation (apart from some adapter methods to delegate to methods with other parameter types for the purpose of implementing generic types). Assume you had something like this

```
/**
 * interface for objects who allow adding some other objects
 */
interface Addable<T> {
   /** returns the sum of this object and another object. */
   T plus(T summand);
}
```

Then we could create our `sum` method with two arguments:

```
public static <T extends Addable<T>> T sum(T first, T second) {
    return first.plus(second);
}
```

The static method is compiled to the same bytecode like this (with additional type information in annotations):

```
public static Addable sum(Addable first, Addable second) {
    return first.plus(second);
}
```

This is called **type erasure**.

Now this method can be called for every pair of two elements of an addable type, like this one:

```
public class Integer implements Addable<Integer> {
    public Integer plus(Integer that) {
       return new Integer(this.value + that.value);
    }

     // private implementation details omitted
}
```

What here happens is that the compiler creates an additional synthetic method like this:

```
public Object plus(Object that) {
    return this.plus((Integer)that);
}
```

This method will only be called by generic code with the right types, this guarantees the compiler, assuming you are not doing some unsafe casts somewhere - then the `(Integer)` cast here will catch the mistake (and throw a ClassCastException).

The `sum` method now **always** calls the `plus` method of the first object, there is no way around this. There is not code generated for every type argument possible (this **is** the key difference between Java generics and C++ templates), so we can't simply replace one of the generated method with a specialized one.

Of course, you can create a second `sum` method like *irreputable* proposed (with overloading), but this will only be selected if you use the `MyX` type directly in source code, not when you are calling the `sum` method from some other generic code which happens to be parametrized with MyX, like this:

```
public static <T extends Addable<T>> product (int times, T factor) {
    T result = factor;
    while(n > 1) {
        result = sum(result, factor);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now `product(5, new MyX(...))` will call our `sum(T,T)` method (which in turn calls the `plus` method), not any overloaded `sum(MyX, MyX)` method.

(JDK 7 adds a new `dynamic` method dispatch mode which allows specialization by every argument on run time, but this is not used by the Java language, only intended to be used by other JVM-based languages.)

Comment: the type erased method should be `Addable sum(Addable first, Addable second)`

Comment: Great explanation of how the Generic works for `sum`. Now I can translate that into my old Java knowledge. But what exaclty is *erased* here? What does the name "Type erasure" refer to?

Comment: Of course! Specialization by overloading. How stupid of me :-) That's ot. Thx.

Comment: @towi: "Type erasure" refers to the process where each generic type (which may be a parametrized type, generic array type or type variable) is converted to a non-generic type, since the VM can only work with those directly. See the section [4.6 Type Erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.6) in the JLS.

Answer (score 3):

no - but your particular problem is more of an overloading issue.

There's no problem to define 2 `plus` methods like these

```
<T extends Addable> 
T   plus(T   a, T   b) { .. }

MyX plus(MyX a, MyX b) { .. }
```

This works even if `MyX` is an `Addable`; javac knows that  the 2nd `plus` is more specific than the 1st `plus`, so when you call `plus` with two `MyX` args, the 2nd `plus` is chosen. In a sense Java does allow "specialized" version of methods:

```
f(T1, T2, .. Tn)

f(S1, S2, .. Sn)
```

works great if each `Si` is a subtype of `Ti`

For generic classes, we can do

```
class C<T extends Number> { ... }

class C_Integer extends C<Integer>{ ... }
```

caller must use `C_Integer` instead of `C<Integer>` to pick the "specialized" version.

---

On duck typing: Java is more strict in static typing - unless it is a Duck, it is not a duck.

Comment: This is only overloading, it does not work if the `plus` method is called from some generic method using `T` and called with `MyX`.

Answer (score 2):

HI,

java Generics it's different from C++ template.

Example:

Java code:

```
 public <T> T sum(T a, T b) {
  T newValue = a.sum(b);
  return newValue;
 }
```

In java this code don't work because generics base is class java.lang.Object, so you can use only method of this class.

you can construct this methis like this:

```
public <T extends Number> T sum(T a, T b) {
  T newValue = a.sum(b);
  return newValue;
 }
```

in this case the base of generics is class java.lang.Number so you can use Integer, Double, Long ecc..

method "sum" depend of  implementation of java.lang.Number.

Bye